# In a Web API, isn't providing a DELETE ALL too dangerous?

Tags: asp.net-web-api, api-design

In studying Web API design (regardless of the specific technology), I often come across these two uses of the `DELETE` verb:

```
DELETE /SomeResource/123   /* deletes entity with ID 123 */
DELETE /SomeResource/      /* deletes all entities */
```

I always get the feeling that there's something wrong with providing the latter as an operation in most applications. In rare cases where the resource is trivial, sure, why not just blow the whole collection away without a second thought? And yes, I understand that typically it's the client app's job to present an "Are you sure?" confirmation. But I like to envision my API being driven in a *safe* way even by some low-level agent like Fiddler.

So is there some mechanism I'm missing, like a way for the server/API to initiate some kind of dialog with the client agent to get confirmation before blowing away 10,000 customer records?

**EDIT**
Yes, assume that I *do* want to provide the functionality to remove all entities in a given scenario, but feel compelled to avoid it because of the perceived danger (typos, not paying attention, etc; the things that a UI confirmation dialog is for)

Comment: Looks more like a topic for Programmers.SE than for Stack Overflow. That being said: you're building an API. APIs have to be used responsibly. There's also SQL's DELETE statement, a `List<T>`'s `Clear()` method and so on.

Comment: You can make sure the right user is logged in for that kind of function, like an admin. If any user can delete all data is a requirement then you don't have much to worry about, other than re-confirming the requirement after bringing the potential risk to their attention.

Comment: @AD.Net: how is this confirming achieved through raw API interaction (i.e. no GUI client, just Fiddler)

Comment: @BCA, you can always authenticate the user, you should take a look at the authentication flow with web api. One common approach is to have some sort of token in the header, if it's not there the API will return 403, then the client should authenticate with some other endpoint/page and use the token in the header for the api

Comment: @mmcrae Even a legit admin can make a typo or mistakenly use the wrong verb in Fiddler

Comment: @BCA - at the end of the day what are your requirements? If it seems too dangerous and it's not required, then don't make it an end point in your API. And then when some client/screen wants that end-point, make sure it's locked down and clear what it will do

Comment: If you want to prevent the typo, then use the api behind a UI, where you confirm if the admin wants to delete all data

Answer (score -1):

**You'll NEVER present the option to do a delete all function in a web api.**

While there may be exceptions, its usually an awful idea to do this because it allows a user to perform an irreversible action.  On the other hand, think of how awful it would be to have someone with ill intent find this endpoint!

Most libraries such as ASP.NET will require each method to be implemented explicitly before accepting a request (this is handled in ASP.NET during routing).  So, if you don't provide `DELETE /someresource/` the problem will never come up.  This is particularly great, because you can't accidentally blow away data with a typo.

If you really, really want this functionality, you'll want to be 100% sure you have a reason to have it because this is a dangerous, dangerous endpoint to have.

Bottom line? I wouldn't provide it to protect your data.

Comment: I suppose this question was written under the presumption that a function to remove all entities at a given endpoint is necessary, thereby negating the usefulness of the answer _"you don't need such a function"_.

Comment: @CodeCaster Fair point, but I'm having trouble coming up with a reason i'd want that functionality to sit at `delete /someresource/`.  Honestly, i'd park it somewhere deeper like `delete /account/someresource/` and make sure there was a way to go back.

Comment: Though, the question in the title literally asks if its dangerous to provide this, which I feel i answered. IDK, i need to go back and read the how-to-answer thing I think.